# How to convert a json file to a bitmap image?

Tags: json, python-3.x, bitmapimage

I am having a json file "data.json" and few data to show is:

```
[{
    "id":"Tl134567",
    "type": "Action",
    "cmd":"something"

},
{
    "id":"Sg1235",
    "type": "Passive",
    "cmd":"something1"
}]
```

now I am trying to pass this file as input and trying to convert this into a bitmap image  m getting a string as an output but while decoding it back m not getting the content don't know whether i have done the conversion of Json into bitmap image properly or not.

here is my code:

```
        file = open('data.json')
        content=json.loads(file.read())
    
        def base64_2_mask(s):
            z = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(s))
            n = np.fromstring(z,np.uint8 )
            mask = cv2.imdecode(n, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)[:, :, 3].astype(bool)
            return mask
    
        def mask_2_base64(mask):
            img_pil = Image.frombytes("L",(3,2),np.array(mask))
            img_pil.putpalette([0,0,0,255,255,255])
            bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
            img_pil.save(bytes_io, format='PNG', transparency=0, optimize=0)
            bytes = bytes_io.getvalue()
            return base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(bytes)).decode('utf-8')
    
        for lst in content:
            for con in lst.items():
               encoded_string = mask_2_base64(con)
       print(encoded_string)
       print("last",base64_2_mask(encoded_string))
```

Comment: _Why_ do you need to turn that JSON file into a bitmap image in the first place? As it is, you're not actually even working with JSON, you're working with Python data parsed from JSON. Secondly, are you absolutely sure you're using `python-2.7`, as you've tagged?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please format your code properly.  While I tried to edit your code, I'm not sure I had done it properly so I reverted.  Please ensure your code is formatted properly, particularly those last two lines (```print(encoded_string) print("last",base64_2_mask(encoded_string))```.  I am guessing those two lines should be using the same # of indents as ```encoded_string = mask_2_base64(con)```.

Comment: @ewokx I have edited my code now. you can have a look at it.

Comment: @AKX m currently using python 3.9.

Comment: I don't think your two print statements should be there as you'll only be printing the very last encoded_string.   What happens if you indent those two lines flush to the previous line```encoded_string = mask_2_base64(con)```?

Comment: @ewokx i have tried it but the output is coming as same only and Thanks a lot for welcoming me to the community.